# jQuery get the form name from the form i'm submitting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery code that sends serliazes the formData I'm submitting from any html page. But what if a html page have multiple forms in it ? how can I know what form I'm submitting ?
I'm trying to have a log of the activities I'll be doing on any html page, so without making changes to html code, how can I get the form data of a particular form on a webpage that contains more than one form.

```
$( "*",document.body ).submit(function( event ) {   
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

this is the function I wrote but it'll work on any submitted form without knowing which one it is.

Comment: `this.name` is the name of the current form.

Comment: There is the `id` and the `name` as Richard and Barmar have said, but you can create a perfectly valid form that has neither of those. If you are handling form submission completely via javascript you don't even need `action` or `method` attributes. If you are not the one building the forms then you'll need to state that an id or name is required, or otherwise account for that in your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id` prop, so you can select each form with `$('#id')`, and you can add that prop by JavaScript, without needing to mess with the HTML itself. As stated before by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), using `this.name` you give you the name of the current form, so you can iterate all the forms in the page, and accessing the name (and other atributes as well) of each one, this way you can have better control in whatever you need to do with each form.

Answer (score 1):

you can acces all atribute form using this keyword , wich represent current submited form

by example identifying your form wether by id , name ... , add to each one an id then use

javascript => `this.name` or jQuery => `$(this).attr('name')`

see below snippet:

```js
$( "*",document.body ).submit(function( event ) {   
  console.clear();
  console.log("form id =",$(this).attr("id"));
  console.log("form name =",$(this).attr("name"));
  // or console.log("form id =", this.id);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myFirstForm" id="one">
  <input name="one" type="text" value="text1" />
</form>

<form name="mySecondForm" id="two">
  <input name="two" type="text" value="text2" />
</form>

<form name="myThirdForm" id="three">
  <input name="three" type="text" value="text3" />
</form>
```